# How can I two activities in a listview?

Tags: android, listview

I have two activities and I need to put them in a listview so that when user select a specific listview item, that activity starts. Below is my code unfortunately it ends with message" unfortunately the app has stopped. What is wrong and how should I correct it?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        arrayList.add("kiriari");
        arrayList.add("kenga");

        final ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(list_info);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                if(position == 1)
                {

                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, kiriariActivity.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                }

                if(position == 2)
                {

                    Intent myIntent =  new Intent(MainActivity.this,kengaActivity.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                    String clickedItem = (String) list.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, clickedItem, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside `onItemClick` position is always 0 indexed. So, you have to do like below:

```
 if(position == 0)
 {

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, kiriariActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
 }
 else if(position == 1)
 {
    Intent myIntent =  new Intent(MainActivity.this,kengaActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
 }
```

Your crash might be on `String clickedItem = (String) list.getItemAtPosition(position);` line. or you forgot to add `kiriariActivity` or `kengaActivity` into manifest file.

Comment: How should I add it on manifest file. Also, how should I correct the line?

Comment: Add these below your MainActivity Tag in manifest.xml file. ` <activity android:name=".kiriariActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity android:name=".kengaActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>`